# Помогите составить shell скрипт

Tags: linux, shell

Мне нужно с помощью shell(bash или sh) скрипта запустить процесс в фоне, после запуска записать его pid в файл, а если процесс остановится нужно выполнить кое какое действие.
Возможно ли такое сделать?
С запуском в фоне и записью pid в файл легко справится, а вот как выполнить действие после остановки процесса не знаю.

Comment: Оберните нужный скрипт другим, последний и запускайте уже его в фоне, пусть вложенный делает всё что вам нужно, и управление  вернётся к вашему по окончанию выполнения вложенного.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть, сработает так:

```
{ ./process; echo finished; } &
echo started: $!
```

На моём Cygwin'е, однако, выдаёт PID запущенного подшелла.

---

Вот ещё вариант, без подшелла:

```
./process &
PID=$!
echo started: $PID
wait $PID
echo finished
```

---

Ещё один вариант, в котором не блокируется шелл в ожидании процесса:

```
{ bash -c './process & echo $! ; wait $! ; echo finished >/dev/tty' & } | while read pid
do
    echo started $pid
    break
done
```

Comment: Также возвращает pid подшела да и порядок действий не тот, мне нужно сначало записать pid, а потом уже если остановится echo finished;

Comment: Порядок действий как раз тот, `echo finished` выполняется после того, как `./process` отработал. А вот с PID'ом подшелла, конечно, неприятность.

Comment: Но не после того как я запишу pid.

Comment: @Виталий: На моём хосте выполняется в таком порядке: (1) стартует фоновый подшелл, (2) в нём стартует процесс, (3) выполняется `echo started $!` в основном шелле, (4) я завершаю процесс, (5) в фоновом подшелле выполняется `echo finished`. У вас не так?

Comment: @Виталий: Добавил ещё вариант с ожиданием

Comment: Да, что-то я затупил по крупному, не учел что процесс в фоне запустится.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ top &
[1] 9315
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 top
$ ps 9315
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 9315 pts/0    T<     0:00 top
```

jobs - показывает фоновые процессы

ps - список всех прцессов